# 'store is in an inconsistent state' after upgrading to tezos-node 12.0

Tags: node

```
tezos-node    | Mar 22 07:16:10.676 - node.store: the store is in an inconsistent state: tezos-node    | Mar 22 07:16:10.676 - node.store:  Error: tezos-node    | Mar 22 07:16:10.676 - node.store:     The block 'current_head' is unexpectedly missing from the store.
```

have this problem on two machines after updating...

Comment: How did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed unexpected. Can you give more information regarding:

- from which version it was the upgrade
- which network
- which history mode
- which "binary" used (from sources, docker, opam, …)

In addition to that, can you provide more logs as well as the command used to run/upgrade?

In any case, the node will automatically try to restore the consistency of the node. Was it successful? Is your node running well now?

Comment: It was upgrading from v11.1 to v12.0.  Both machines are on mainnet. One machine is running docker as an archive node. The other machine was running a binary directly compiled from gitlab source as a full node. Both are working great now, but it was an unexpected hiccup especially with the archive node.

Comment: Ok, good to know. It is know that the archive nodes are heavier to run but this kind of error should no occur if the node was not terminated brutally. Please do not hesitate to report any similar issue.